# HDF5: How to add field column names to a dataset using the C++ wrapper API?

Tags: c++, c++11, hdf5

I'm using the HDF5's wrapper C++ API, and I want to add field names (aka column names) to my 2D dataset (a table).
I saw clear instructions in [the High Level Table API](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/HL/RM_H5TB.html), but unfortunately it is only available in C.

It's a simple task but I could not find any relevant information on [the C++ API documentation](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/index.html) or stackoverflow.

Could someone provide a simple example for this?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to call into the C library from your classes? I think all H5x_some_name are wrapped with extern "C" { ... };

Comment: I found the way to do it in the source code of HDF5 Table API, H5TBmake_table.